# How to Access a specific Grid Item in a Grid View using position

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to set padding for specific grid items in my grid view. I'm getting null value for gridChild while trying to get it's view using getChildAt

I'm writing this code at onCreate() method:

```
GridView MainGalleryview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.main_gallery_gridview);
        MainGalleryview.setAdapter(new CustomGalleryAdapter(this));
        final CustomGalleryAdapter adapterData = new CustomGalleryAdapter(this);

        for(int i = 0; i<adapterData.getCount(); i++ ) {
            mediaPath = adapterData.images.get(i);
            boolean ImageCheck = mediaPath.indexOf("WhatsApp/") > 0;
            Log.d("Check: ", "-----" + mediaPath +"----");
            if(ImageCheck){
                ViewGroup gridChild = (ViewGroup) MainGalleryview.getChildAt(i);
                if(gridChild != null)
                    gridChild.setPadding(-10, -10, -10, -10 );
                else
                    Log.d("Error: ", "*******" + gridChild + "********");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set view padding  in your adpater getView method. It seems the nullpointer comes from the adapterData.images variable.

Comment: It seems that you forgot something in your answer, you're asking the OP to do something without specifying it

Comment: @Tamas Kandala: I checked my logs and i'm sure nullpointer is not from adapterData.images. How can I use getChildAt in my adapter class?